# History.js issue with loading other scripts and extreme CPU usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I'm having some serious issues with my `History.js/Ajaxify` script. The main problem is that after a page has been loaded with history.js (by clicking a link), the other javascript in the `<header>` tag aren't loaded, in fact it's as if they've been unloaded.

To fix this problem I decided to load the scripts with `statechangecomplete` which I realised after some time, only caused more problems. Because not only does it load the scripts **every time** I click a link, but after a few page changes Chrome reaches 100% CPU usage.

```
$(window).on('statechangecomplete', function() {
    $.getScript(document.location.origin + "/js/myscript1.js");
    $.getScript(document.location.origin + "/js/myscript2.js");
    $.getScript(document.location.origin + "/js/myscript3.js");
});
```

Meanwhile my `<head>` consists of this:

```
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOODP">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//balupton.github.io/jquery-scrollto/lib/jquery-scrollto.js"></script>
    <script src="//browserstate.github.io/history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/ajaxify-html5.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/myscript1.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/myscript2.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/myscript3.js"></script>
</head>
```

The weirdest part about this is that both `uikit.min.js` and `mithril.js` works after a page change. After looking through their code and comparing it to mine, I'm starting to suspect the reason to why my code isn't working as it should is because they all contain `$(document).ready(function({});` while the `mithril` and `uikit` do not.

In the end I'm wondering why it causes my scripts to not load after a page change/history pushstate?

Comment: ... what's the question? You want us to diagnose why you get 100% CPU usage in chrome from a listing of HTML code? We can't possibly know what's in "myscript1.js" that could be causing it for example.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Oh, sorry about that. I updated OP with the "real" question!

Comment: Remove the stuff about CPU usage if it is not relevant to the question. Also, please provide a MCVE that shows it not working. See [mcve].

Answer (score -2):

I found the issue, **for anyone having the same issue as me**, what I did was to delete

```
    var result = String(html)
                    .replace(/<\!DOCTYPE[^>]*>/i, '')
                    .replace(/<(html|head|body|title|meta|script)([\s\>])/gi,'<div class="document-$1"$2')
                    .replace(/<\/(html|head|body|title|meta|script)\>/gi,'</div>')
                ;

return $.trim(result);
```

From `ajaxify-html5.js`. This will make it so it doesn't remove the script tags etc.